# How to find the eigenvalues of a linear operator in general?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

My professor assigned us this exercise in class:-

> Let $V = \mathbb R^{10}$. List five linear maps in $L(V,V)$ (other
>   than the identity map and the zero map) and check if they're
>   diagonizable.

In an attempt to answer this, I tried the following:-

Let $\{e_1,e_2,....e_n\}$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb R^{10}$. I'll define my linear maps by specifying the mappings of the basis elements.

So, for my first map, consider $f: \mathbb R^{10} \rightarrow \mathbb R^{10}$ defined by $f(e_1) = e_2$, $f(e_2) = e_1$, $f(e_i) = e_i  \forall i \in \{3,4,...10\}$.

But after this point, I'm confused on how to find the eigenvalues and check if a basis of eigenvectors can be constructed (to check diagonizability). I was specifically told **not to use matrices** (not that it easy anyway, considering $V = \mathbb R^{10}$).

> So how do I find the eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors of
>   this $f$ **without resorting to its matrix representation**?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that eigenvectors are the vectors when applied the transformation, they do not rotate (expect for 180 degrees).

In your example, the $e_i$'s when $i=3,4,...$ are all eigenvectors, and since $f(e_i)=e_i$, corresponding eigenvalues are $1$.

For $e_1$ and $e_2$, notice that $f(e_1-e_2)=e_2-e_1=-(e_1-e_2)$, this gives you an eigenvector with eigenvalue $-1$. Can you find another one?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I did obtain the eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$, in the way you mentioned. And I don't think there are any others, but how do I prove this?

Comment: Also, what if the maps turn out to be more complex. Finding eigenvalues in this manner wouldn't work then, would it?

Comment: There are already $10$ eigenvalues, counting multiplicity, which is what you need. Regarding to your second question, I think the purpose of the problem is for you to find some simple maps that you can find eigenvectors and eigenvalues easily.

Comment: I see, thank you. I have one more question; can the algebraic multiplicity of an eigenvalue be defined without the characteristic polynomial? Because the characteristic polynomial comes from the matrix representation of the map, and I was wondering if the multiplicity could be found without explicitly counting them all.

Comment: In this case, you can. Since the eigenvectors are apparently independent, and algebraic multiplicity is greater than or equal to geometric multiplicity, you can then determine the algebraic multiplicity of the eigenvalue. I don't think it is always the case though. If the eigenvectors are more complicated, you might not be able to find all eigenvalues.